# Send email with VBA through excel with already saved email template in folder?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a list of emails in excel that I want to send a already premade email in outlook that I have saved as a templet in a folder. Instead of trying to recreate this email through VBA. I am curious to know if I can just have the saved Outlook template be sent to each email.

Comment: Have you tried using MailMerge?

Comment: I don't know what that is.

Comment: Would this not be noted as SPAM?

Comment: MailMerge only prints I need to send this as a email.

Comment: MailMerge sends emails as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for the template. You likely want to pass the email and content variables to the function, but it sounds like you can use what you already got to reconfigure that part.

```
Sub CreateEmailfromTemplate()
    Dim obApp As Application
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\directory\Template.oft")
    NewMail.Display
    With NewMail
        .To = "example@mail.com"
        .Display
    End With

    Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub
```